# Casting char* to a linked list

Tags: c++, casting, linked-list, byte, nodes

My linked-list:

```
struct Node{
    bool inUse;
    unsigned int size;
    Node *next;
};
```

Total bytes = 12 with padding.

```
tmp->inUse = true;
tmp->size = size;
tmp->next = (Node*)((char*)(tmp + 2));
```

The problem is in my `tmp->next`. I am trying to get `tmp->next`  to point to the second byte of `tmp`.
But it moves `24 bytes` tmp + 2 = 24 bytes.

Since I am casting char* to it I expect it to move 2 bytes starting from `tmp`.
Where do I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try tmp->next = (Node*)((char*)tmp + 2); I just strip off the parentesis.

Comment: Why would you do that? `Node*` should point to a whole `Node`, not to one of its parts.

Comment: @Tomás Badan Oh my god, I've been trying to solve this for hours. I guess I only needed to cast char* to the temp. And the parentheses made them calculate before getting cast to char*. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tomás Badan already said
(Node*)((char*)(tmp + 2)); should do what you explaied, because tmp + 2 moves two steps forward in the size of the tmp data (sizeof(Node)). But what you are trying with the pointers seems very obscure.

Comment: Yeah, I was calculating some other stuff instead of just 2. Just wanted to simplify my question. Thanks. I'll just accept this one so this question is marked as answered.